# Mcrypt and Drupal installations

Tags: php, drupal, mcrypt

Is MCrypt a standard part of Drupal installations? Can I assume that it is installed wherever Drupal is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Drupal works fine without mcrypt.

It might be that some addon (module) requires mcrypt, though.

Comment: hmm - would youhappen to know where i can learn more about 'standard' php setups and how many % of people have mcrypt installed?

Comment: Maybe serverfault.com can help you with such metrics.